# How can i share same ViewModel between two views in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have this view:

```
<Window x:Class="Ohmio.Client.PruebasView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ohmio.Client"   
    Title="Pruebas" Height="284" Width="626">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:PruebasViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Create View"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Create child View" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPrt" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5"></ContentPresenter>        
</Grid>
```

My idea is to load a second view(child view) in the content presenter. Just for testing i'm doing this from code-behind:

```
this.ContentPrt.Content = new ModalViewModel();
```

**So my question is:** How can I make the new view(the one load on contentPresenter) share the same dataContext with PruebasView? (In this case, PruebasViewModel)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? Mvvm Light/Caliburn/etc...? It can have an impact on how to reference ViewModels.

Comment: Yes @goobering. Forgot to mention, sorry. I'm ussing Caliburn.Micro.  The idea is to split a complex view into two views that share same viemodel wich have properties for the two views (I need to share same instance of the viewmodel). Thanks!

Comment: IMO it never makes sense to share *ViewModels* - you should just point both viewmodels to the same shared-resource instead. How you can do this is basically dependent on the way you create your view/viewmodels.

Comment: You bind the Content property of the content presenter to your VM?  Have a DataTemplate ready to go to display it properly? Your question seems too simple to be what it appears to ask.  (edit) Hmmm... maybe you want to have two view models in the content presenter at the same time? I'm baffled.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, it's simple. Just pass PruebasViewModel to ContentPresenter as the data context.

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPrt" DataContext={Binding} Grid.Row="2" Margin="5"></ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this didn't work for me. The viewModel for the child view is created (Constructor is called) but it seems like the child view won't link with it's viewmodel methods neither the parent viewmodel ones.Don't know what im i doing wrong here

Comment: `DataContext={Binding}` is the most redundant thing ever since the redundant redundantcy decreed that redundants shall redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `ModalViewModel` is your child view class. So when you add it to the content presenter, your View becomes a part of your Visual Tree, so it *automatically* shares the `DataContext` of the main window.

Pratically WPF makes of the job for you: the content presenter's content will "see" the PruebasViewModel by its own.

**EDIT**

I did not read that you are using Caliburn Micro, but the idea does not change.

Comment: This doesn't work either. ModalViewModel is the child viewmodel. From within the child view, i cannot Access methods on child viewmodel. Doesnt' work on parent viewmodel either.

Comment: @ericpap, I did not read your comment about Caliburn Micro, so my answer regards the generic WPF behaviour. Since I do not know Caliburn, probably I do not understand your question. Can you post the new View, the PruebasViewModel? Which properties of PruebasViewModel do you want to access from the new View?